# What influences Avg. Disk Sec/Read beyond hardware?

Tags: sql-server

I have been monitoring the performance of an OLTP database (approx. 150GB); the average disk sec/read and average disk sec/write values are exceeding 20 ms over a 24hr period.

I need to arrive at a clear explanation as to why the business application has no influence over the 'less-than-stellar' performance on these counters.  I also need to exert some pressure to have the storage folk re-examine their configuration as it applies to the placement of the mdf, ldf and tempdb files on their SAN.  At present, my argument is shaky but I am pressing my point with people who don't understand the difference between IOPs and disk latency.

Beyond the limitations of physical hardware and the placement of data files across physical disks, is there anything else that would influence these counter values?  For instance: the number of transactions per second, the size of the query, poorly written queries or missing indexes?  My readings say 'no' but I need a voice of authority in this debate.

Comment: All of the above and there isn't enough info - eg if you don't have enough RAM, there will be a lot of IO. If queries load a lot of data at a time, you'll get large transfers. What does SQL Server's activity monitor say? What do the server's DMVs say? Activate Data Collection (under Management in SSMS) to get useful metrics

Comment: Thank you for the reply Panagiotis.  Hi Roger.  Thank you for the reply.  I had though "avg disk sec/read" was a measure of disk latency rather than disk IO.   I had understood read latency (for example) to be the time required for the controller to find the proper data blocks and place the heads over those blocks (including the time needed to spin the disk platters).  That is to say, to begin the transfer process.

Comment: I understand that limited RAM leads to more disk operations but I don't understand how that would affect "avg disk sec/read" and  "avg disk sec/write."  These counters appear to measure the physical abilities of the disk subsystem.

Comment: @ianv, yes, it is close to latency, but it also depends on the load profile. You see, "sec/read" is an average time to perform a single read request, and requests, unlike sectors or pages, can vary wildly in size. So it pays to check, for example, the `Avg. Disk Bytes/Read` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are "a lot" of factors that can affect the overall latency.  To truly rule it as SAN or not, you will want to look at the "Avg. Disk sec/Read counter" and the "Avg. Desk sec/Write Counter", that you mentioned.   Just make sure you are looking at the "Physical Disk" object, and not the "Logical Disk" object.  The logical disk counter includes the file system overhead, and may be different, depending on different factors.

Once you have the counters for the physical disks, you will want to compare them to the latency counters for the Storage unit, the server is connected to.  You mentioned "storage folk" So I'm going to assume that is a different team, hopefully they will be nice and provide the info to you.

If it is a Storage unit issue, then both of these counters should match up pretty good.  That indicates the storage unit is truly running slow.  If the storage unit counters show significantly better, then it's something in between.  Depending on what type of storage network you are using this would be the HBA/NIC/Switches that connect the server and storage together.  Or if it's a VM then the host machine stats would prove useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from obvious reasons such as "not enough memory for buffer pool", latency mostly depends on how your storage is actually implemented.

If your server has external SAN, usually its problem is that it might give you stellar throughput, but it will never (again, usually) give you stellar latency. It's just the way things are. It might become a real headache for heavy loaded OLTP systems, sure.

So, if you are about to squeeze every last microsecond from your storage, most probably you will need local drives. That, and your RAID 10 should have enough spindles to cope with the load.